# Unexpected projection

Tags: opengl

It should be rect, which will takes whole width of window. I am expecting this, because frustum width is -5 to 5 and rect size is 10x10 and rect is on same z-axis position like near plnane of frustum. Result is very small and doesn't look like a rect, i don't know why?

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {

    glViewport(0,0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    double ratio = (double)w/(double)h;
    double size = ((10.0/ratio)/2.0);
    glFrustum(-5.0, 5.0, -size, size, 10.0, 50.0);

}

void GLWidget::paintGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-5.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();


}
```

Comment: Try writing your program to accept keyboard input, that changes the parameters you pass to methods like frustrum, and display the currently being used values on screen. Then you can alter the values in real time until you know what you're doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be rect, which will takes whole width of window.

Well, then switch your projection to something better suited, an ortho projection, for the task when drawing the rect. Also you must reset your projection matrix to identity before applying frustum or ortho.

Hint: All the code in your `resizeGL` should go into the `paintGL` method. I see you're using Qt, so you can get the widget's width and height conveniently using the `width` and `height` getter functions. Also `glClearColor` goes into `painGL` as well:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {


}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    double const ratio = (double)width()/(double)height();
    double const size = ((10.0/ratio)/2.0);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0,0, width(), height());
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-5.0, 5.0, -size, size, 10.0, 50.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

    draw_perspective_stuff();

    glViewport(0,0, width(), height());
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // using identity projection, this fills the viewport
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.f, -1.f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.f, -1.f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 1.f,  1.f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.f,  1.f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```